# Double cannot be cast to String

Tags: java, swing, casting, jtable

So, I'm finishing up my POS Program and I can't find out why this code doesn't work to sum all of the prices shown after being input into the `JTable`. It shows:

```
java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

---

```
double total = 0;

DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();

    for(int i = 0; i<model.getRowCount();i++){
        String number = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i,5);
        double totals = Double.parseDouble(number);
        total+=totals;
    }
    jLabel12.setText(String.valueOf(total));
```

Comment: What is the return type of `jTable1.getValueAt(i,5);`?

Comment: It seems to be already double so don' cast it to String in the first place. Try `double totals= jTable1.getValueAt(i,5)` and remove the line `String number = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i,5);`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `toString()` instead of casting,

```
String number = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 5).toString();
```

---

Side note: 6<sup>th</sup> column's data type of your `jTable1` may be `double`. Try,

```
double number = (Double) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 5);
```